# Compiling software generated with an old version of Qt Designer

Tags: compiling, qt

I'm trying to compile and install K3dsurf following the instructions in the "Readme", which says:

```
tar -xvzf k3dsurf-0.6.2.tar.gz;
cd k3dsurf;
qmake; make;
./bin/k3dsurf & ;
```

The problem is that when I execute make, the following error message appears:

> cd src/ && make -f Makefile 
>   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/miguel/Downloads/k3dsurf-0.6.2/src'
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/uic k3dsurf.ui -o ui_k3dsurf.h
>   uic: File generated with too old version of Qt Designer (3.3)
>   File 'k3dsurf.ui' is not valid
>   make[1]: *** [ui_k3dsurf.h] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/miguel/Downloads/k3dsurf-0.6.2/src'
>   make: *** [sub-src-make_default] Error 2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the program depends on an outdated version of Qt Designer (3.3). In theory, that is fixable; but I would guess it would be just the first in a long chain of outdated dependencies.

The basic problem is that program has not been updated since 2007. Debian [removed the package from both testing and unstable in June, 2012](http://packages.qa.debian.org/k/k3dsurf.html). Ubuntu [removed the package from 12.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/k3dsurf/+changelog) both because Debian did so and because it depends on obsolete Qt3 libraries.

`k3dsurf` is, however, available in the Universe repository in 12.04. If you are already running 12.04 or can install 12.04 to a new partition or to an external drive, that is your best bet for using the program.

The most recent version `0.6.2.4-1` is available directly from the Software Center, so you won't need to worry about installing from source.

Update: The OP stated in a comment that the `k3dsurf` Windows version runs fine under Wine.

Given that the software is fairly old and is using an older version of Qt, it may a good idea to be aware of security risks with Wine, no matter how unlikely they may be.

[The Wine FAQ on risks](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-1c91cac836dd52754c846d2ef62be4f346eebe87) states:

> Just because Wine runs on a non-Windows OS doesn't mean you're protected from viruses, trojans, and other forms of malware.

[Securing Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/SecuringWine) on the Wine Wiki warns:

> Wine doesn't support most Windows security constructs, and instead relies on the underlying operating system for security. Unless you run Wine as root, for instance, it's hard for malicious software in Wine to modify files belonging to other users. But Wine doesn't protect you against malware you run yourself.

Both pages go on to list several ways to improve security.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I just installed the Windows version using wine and it works perfectly :D

Comment: Great. I'm glad it worked out. And thanks for accepting the answer. You are obviously familiar with Wine, but I'll add the info on Wine along with a security warning for older software for future readers.